# Partitioning an HFS+/MBR-formatted external drive without data loss

Tags: partitioning, backup, mbr, hfs+, disk-formatting

(Likely a duplicate, but Google is failing me)

I have a 2 TB external hard drive, formatted with a single HFS+ partition and an MBR partitioning scheme. It's currently holding a backup of my old Macbook.

Fast forward a few years, I'm upgrading from an old PC running Ubuntu 19.10 to a newer PC running Kubuntu 22.04, and I'd like to backup the old PC to a second partition on the external drive before retiring it for good, without losing the data on the existing HFS+ partition.

Between the outdated MBR scheme and the unsupported HFS+ filesystem, I'm having trouble figuring out the best way to achieve this.

---

Possibly relevant info:

1. I'm not planning on restoring anything from either backup (the Macbook or the old PC), just store their contents in a convenient place while migrating the stuff I'd like to keep onto my new machine.
2. I no longer have access to a Mac for working with the HFS+ partition.
3. I originally backed up the Mac by formatting the backup drive with an empty HFS+ partition and just drag-and-drop copying the Mac's root directory (don't ask why, it was a long time ago).
4. If I can't achieve this without wiping the backup drive, I don't mind temporarily backup an image of the HFS+ partition elsewhere; as is, it's too large to store on either PC, but could most likely fit on my new PC with compression.

I've included a summary of the current state of each drive (as reported by `lsblk`, formatted for readability). `sda` is the old PC, `nvme0n1` is the new PC, and `sdb` is the backup drive. `sda2` through `sda5` are a (mostly unused) Windows 10 install; `sda6` is the only partition I'm interested in backing up. All sizes are in GiB:

```
NAME        | PTTYPE | FSTYPE  | SIZE       | FSSIZE   | FSAVAIL  | FSUSED 
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
sda         | gpt    |         |    931.513 |          |          |        
|-sda1      | gpt    | vfat    |      0.488 |    0.484 |    0.447 |   0.038
|-sda2      | gpt    |         |      0.125 |          |          |        
|-sda3      | gpt    | ntfs    |    458.026 |          |          |        
|-sda4      | gpt    | ntfs    |      0.831 |          |          |        
|-sda5      | gpt    | ntfs    |     15.204 |          |          |        
|-sda6      | gpt    | ext4    |    456.836 |  448.665 |  231.923 | 193.884
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
nvme0n1     | gpt    |         |    476.940 |          |          |        
|-nvme0n1p1 | gpt    | vfat    |      0.500 |    0.499 |    0.494 |   0.005
|-nvme0n1p2 | gpt    | ext4    |    476.438 |  467.890 |  422.410 |  21.642
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
sdb         | dos    |         |   1863.017 |          |          |        
|-sdb1      | dos    | hfsplus |   1863.017 | 1863.017 | 1390.504 | 472.513
```

Comment: Any time you work with partitions there is a danger of losing the data.

Comment: obviously; by "without data loss" I just mean without *intentionally* losing data (e.g. by wiping the existing partition and reformatting from scratch)